# При изменении объекта перезаписывается массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Есть объект item и массив arr. Не могу понять, почему при изменении объекта (в момент выполнения item.description = $(this).val();) изменяются и все элементы массива, все они становятся равны новому значению item.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var item = {
        description: ""
    };
   arr = [];

    //если поле input с id="description" изменилось, меняем item.description  
    $('#description').change(function(){
        item.description = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    // при нажатии на кнопку Добавить добавляем новый элемент в массив
    $('#add').click(function() {
        arr.push(item);
    });

});
</script>

</br>
<input id="description" name="description" type="text">
<input id="add" type="submit" value="Добавить"/>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы сохраняете в массив ссылки на один и тот же объект.

После добавления в массив просто присваивайте новый объект переменной `item`

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    arr.push(item);
    item = {
        description: ""
    };
});
```

Либо вообще стоит отказаться от этой переменной

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    arr.push({
        description: $('#description').val()
    });
});
```

В этом случае так же не нужен обработчик `change`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!